# add and remove class on other element using 1 button jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I add/remove a class on another `div` using jQuery? Kindly see my code below. Thanks

```js
$(".btns").on("click", function() {
  $(".box").addClass("addClass")
})
```

```css
.box{
  background: yellow;
}

.box.addClass{
 background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hrd-settings">
  <div class="btns">Button</div>

  <div class="box">
    <div class="box1">History</div>
    <div class="nox1">Logout</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Change `addClass()` to `toggleClass()`.

Comment: I also tried using toggle but there's animation using that is there any way to not use toggle instead using addCLass and removeCLass?

Comment: It would have helped if you had shown the complete example, including animation, in the question. That said, if the animation is configured correctly using CSS then the `toggleClass()` will still work. Can you please edit the question to include a working example of the issue with all relevant code.

Comment: What kind of animation do you have? It shouldn't make a difference if using `.addClass()`+`.removeClass()` or `.toggleClass()` wrt to animations, at least.

Comment: Hi Rory all good now, it's my mistake on my side I only use toggle not toggleClass. But still thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.toggleClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to add or remove classes from an element depending on their absence/presence.

Example:

```js
$(".btns").on("click", function() {
  $(".box").toggleClass("addClass");             // <---- changed this line
})
```

```css
.box{
  background: yellow;
}

.box.addClass{
 background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hrd-settings">
  <div class="btns">Button</div>

  <div class="box">
    <div class="box1">History</div>
    <div class="nox1">Logout</div>
  </div>
</div>
```